# Setting break point using source code line number in WinDBG

Tags: windbg

I am aware of setting breakpoint base on function name in WinDBG using bp, bm commands
is there a way to set break point break on source code line number

say

```
 <some command> 20
```

means it should set breakpoint at line 20

Thanks in advance

Comment: Got the answer bp `Recfib.c:9`  set breakpoint at line 9 of Recfib.c

Answer (score 40):

```
bp `source.c:12`
```

Optionally, you can load the source file in WinDBG, set the cursor to the line you want to set a breakpoint to, and hit F9.

Also try .hh bp for more info

Comment: If anyone else is derping-out, see that you are using the quotation mark at the top left of the keyboard.

Answer (score 7):

Here is the syntax for setting `bp` on line number

```
bp (@@masm(`main.c:8+`))
```

For the above to work `.lines` should be enabled

HTH

Answer (score 2):

Here's the syntax:

> bu `module_name!file.cpp:206`